# Solve the following DE: $ 2y(y'+2)=x(y')^2 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck trying to understand how to solve this differential equation:
$$
2y(y'+2)=x(y')^2
$$
The main problem is to understand what type it is. I have never come across anything like this before. Could anyone give me a hint?

At first, I thought it is a Lagrange equation, so that was my attempt:
$$
y=\frac{x(y')^2}{2y'+4}
$$
$$
y'=p\Rightarrow y'=p=\frac{(p^2+2xpp')(2p+4)-2xp^2}{(2p+4)^2}
$$
And then I got stuck trying to solve this equation for $x$ in terms of $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2y(y'+2)=x(y')^2$$
This is [D'alembert's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation):
$$y=x \left (\dfrac  {y'^2}{2(y'+2)}\right)$$
Is of the form:
$$y=x f(y')+g(y')$$

---

You made a little mistake here :
$$p=\frac{(p^2+2xpp')(2p+4)-2xp^2}{(2p+4)^2}$$
It shoul be:
$$p=\frac{(p^2+2xpp')(2p+4)-2xp^2\color {red}{p'}}{(2p+4)^2}$$
Then it factorize nicely into:
$$p(p+4)(p+2-xp')=0$$

$$
\begin{cases}
p=0 \\
p+4=0 \\
p+2-xp'=0
\end{cases}
$$
And $y=0$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start using $y=x \,z(x)$ to make
$$-x^2 z'(x)^2+z(x)^2+4 z(x)=0$$ Now, switch variables to make
$$\frac{x'}x=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt{4z+z^2}}$$ which seems to be simple.

Comment: How did you find the first expression (after the substitution)?